# How to use custom ini file for Grafana with Docker?

Tags: docker, grafana

I have like this container in my docker-compose file:

```
grafana:
  image: grafana/grafana
  ports:
    - '3000:3000'
  environment:
    - GF_PATHS_CONFIG="./grafana/etc/grafana.ini"
    - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-piechart-panel,grafana-worldmap-panel,vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource,vertamedia-chtable
```

Inside grafana.ini I tried change default admin login and password like this:

```
[security]

admin_user = user
admin_password = 1234
```

But it is doesn’t work for me. How I can use my custom .ini file with Grafana in Docker correctly?

**Grafana version:** Grafana v7.4.3 (010f20c1c8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are 2 things that come to my mind when I saw your compose file.

1. Do I need to change the config path?
2. Where is my custom .ini file?

When running a container with an official image (as grafana/grafana), we cannot change the config without feeding it from the outside. So you should specify it in your compose file as a "volume".

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-piechart-panel,grafana-worldmap-panel,vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource
    volumes:
      - "./grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini"
      - "grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana"
volumes:
  grafana-storage:
```

Also, you have to put your grafana.ini file in the same directory for this compose file to run:

```
[security]

admin_user = user
admin_password = 1234
```

It should work when you run `docker-compose up`.

P.S. I removed `vertamedia-chtable` plugin because it cannot be found by the installer and grafana raised an error.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to previous answer, you can feed every config parameter to grafana via .env file. In this case you don't have to store the config file in the docker-compose directory.

for your case, it would look like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    env_file:
      - config.env
    volumes:
      - "grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana"
volumes:
  grafana-storage:
```

config.env:

```
GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=user
GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=1234
GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-piechart-panel,grafana-worldmap-panel,vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource
```

more info about overriding configuration can be found here: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#override-configuration-with-environment-variables